# Angular 7 - Display username after successful login

Tags: angular, laravel

I am using Angular 7 and Laravel to create user Login. Laravel serves the end point to Angular. I successfully created the user login, but I don't know how to display the logged in username

I have done it that after successful login, it redirects to dashboard page.
I created a service for the login (jarwis.service).

```
jarwis(login) service

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JarwisService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost/cloudengine-sandbox/cloudengine/public/api';
  //private baseUrl = '/api';


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  signup(data){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/signup`, data)
  }
  login(data){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, data)
  }

  sendPasswordResetLink(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/sendPasswordResetLink`,data)
  }
}
```

login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { JarwisService } from '../../services/jarwis.service';
import { TokenService } from '../../services/token.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = {
    email:null,
    password:null
  };

 public error = null;
  constructor(
    private Jarwis:JarwisService,
    private Token:TokenService,
    private router:Router,
    private Auth:AuthService
  ) { }

  onSubmit() {
  this.Jarwis.login(this.form).subscribe(
     data => this.handleResponse(data),
     error => this.handleError(error)
  );
  }

  handleResponse(data){
 this.Token.handle(data.access_token);
 this.Auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }


  handleError(error){
 this.error = error.error.error;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I want to display the username after successful login

Comment: You can navigate adding the username in your `this.router.navigate`

Comment: Essentially, you want to pass the username value from the `LoginComponent` to that component that points to `/home`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set username to `sessionStorage` after success login and use in another component like this

```
handleResponse(data){
  this.Token.handle(data.access_token);
  this.Auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
  sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUser', data.Username);
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}
```

in Home component ts file

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    userDisplayName = '';
    ngOnInit() {
       this.userDisplayName = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser');
    }
}
```

in HTML file

```
<div class="username">Username: {{userDisplayName}}</div>
```

Comment: He/She may want to check if a logged in user exists first though.

Comment: Yes, I assume they check in my answer

Comment: This won't fire the ngOnInit in the NavBarComponet, only the home Component. ngOnInit only fires one time or unless you directly navigate to the Component. Notice in the Home Component you are exporting the NavbarComponent.

Comment: @HienNguyen this solution works but it always show the previously logged in username instead of the last logged in username. When reload whole app manually then  it shows last logged in username. Please help. Appreciate in advanced

Comment: what if component loaded before we set sessionStorage? It will stay undefined